# Golang hide implementation detail of channel

Tags: go, interface, mqtt, abstraction

In my code I have the interface

```
import amqp "github.com/rabbitmq/amqp091-go"

type Consumer interface {
    StartConsuming(queueName, key string) (<-chan amqp.Delivery, error)
}
```

with its impl

```
package rabbitmq

import amqp "github.com/rabbitmq/amqp091-go"

type Consumer struct {
    *Connection
}

func (c Consumer) StartConsuming(queueName, key string) (<-chan amqp.Delivery, error) {
    _, err := c.Channel.QueueDeclare(
        queueName,
        true,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        nil,
    )

    ...

    return c.Connection.Consume(
        queueName,
        "",
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        nil,
    )
}
```

The thing is, in my interface I do not want to specify that it is a delivery of type `amqp.Delivery`, I want it to be a generic message so that I can switch anytime to any other broker e.g. MQTT. But I do not know how you can make this more abstract and less implementation bound so that it can be kept "dumb". Normally it would be rather easy with struct variables etc, but here this channel is a bit still unknown to me.